# Is it safe to delete old files in .local/share/jupyter/runtime?

Tags: file, jupyter-notebook, runtime

I noticed there are a bunch of old files in ./local/share/jupyter/runtime which start with **nbserver-** and **kernerl** and end in either **.json** or **.html**.

I'm guessing for some reason these files were not properly deleted.

Is it safe to delete the old files?

Clearly I don't want to deleted files with dates which could be associated with currently open notebooks.